# Attribute Definitions Inconsistency When Creating DynamoDB Table via CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

When I attempt to build the following:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: Foobar
Resources:
  FailuresTable:
    Type: AWS::DynamoDB::Table
    Properties:
      TableName: Failures
      AttributeDefinitions:
        -
          AttributeName: failureKey
          AttributeType: S
        -
          AttributeName: status,
          AttributeType: S
      KeySchema:
        -
          AttributeName: failureKey
          KeyType: HASH
      GlobalSecondaryIndexes:
        -
          IndexName: failure-status
          KeySchema:
            - AttributeName: status
              KeyType: RANGE
          Projection:
            ProjectionType: ALL
          ProvisionedThroughput:
            ReadCapacityUnits: 5
            WriteCapacityUnits: 15
      ProvisionedThroughput:
        ReadCapacityUnits: 5
        WriteCapacityUnits: 15
```

I get an error, "Property AttributeDefinitions is inconsistent with the KeySchema of the table and the secondary indexes".

I've defined two attributes: failureKey and status. The first is in my table's key. The second is a key in the table's only GSI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first key-column in the global secondary index's key-schema has to be a hash type.

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: Foobar
Resources:
  FailuresTable:
    Type: AWS::DynamoDB::Table
    Properties:
      AttributeDefinitions:
        -
          AttributeName: "failureKey"
          AttributeType: "S"
        -
          AttributeName: "status"
          AttributeType: "S"
      KeySchema:
        -
          AttributeName: "failureKey"
          KeyType: "HASH"
      ProvisionedThroughput:
        ReadCapacityUnits: 5
        WriteCapacityUnits: 5
      TableName: "Failures"
      GlobalSecondaryIndexes:
        -
          IndexName: "failure-status"
          KeySchema:
            -
              AttributeName: "status"
              KeyType: "HASH"
          Projection:
            ProjectionType: "ALL"
          ProvisionedThroughput:
            ReadCapacityUnits: 5
            WriteCapacityUnits: 5
```